# facing a problem "401" when trying to work with workflow on github

Tags: workflow

Hey im trying to create github workflow that:
For every release version of the code will automatically push a dockerized
version of your code to a private repository on DockerHub

and i writed this workflow:

name: Docker Image CI

on:
release:
types:
- created

jobs:
build-and-push:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

  - name: Build and push Docker image
    run: |
      docker buildx create --use
      docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t orile24/ex1:latest -t orile24/ex1:${{ github.event_name }} --push .
      echo "DOCKER_IMAGE_LATEST=orile24/ex1:latest" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo "DOCKER_IMAGE_EVENT=orile24/ex1:${{ github.event_name }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

env:
  DOCKER_CLI_AARCH64: 1
```

### and i get this msg:
#16 ERROR: failed to push orile24/ex1:latest: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Aorile24%2Fex1%3Apull%2Cpush&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized

> exporting to image:

---

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push orile24/ex1:latest: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status from GET request to https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Aorile24%2Fex1%3Apull%2Cpush&service=registry.docker.io: 401 Unauthorized
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

can someone help me undersatnd whats the problem?

tried to :
For every release version of the code will automatically push a dockerized
version of your code to a private repository on DockerHub